# Is there a way to quickly download all of my Kindle books?

Tags: kindle, kindle-app

I have ~165 books in my Kindle cloud library. I am currently trying to download all of them onto my laptop (the Kindle app; I use Windows) so that I can access them when I don't have an internet connection. The way I did it was to select each book and click "Download Book" in the desktop app, but at the rate that it's downloading them, it looks like it is going to take two hours or more (I can watch streamed high-definition video, so I know it isn't my internet connection that's causing this). This process and speed is OK (if somewhat annoying) right now, but for the future I'd like to know if there was a faster way.

So:

1. Is there a one-button way to download all of my Kindle books that will take less than 5 minutes?
2. Why does it take as long as it does to download these books?